# Can't visit any web page but Skype is working perfectly fine

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, internet

#### Context

I have a WiFi network at home through which all the devices at home are connected. I have 2 options to connect, one being 5Ghz and the other being 2.4Ghz. Mostly I am connected to the 5GHz connection.

Lately, I have been facing a problem on my laptop (Windows 10) where web pages stop loading while at the same time applications like Skype work perfectly fine. No other device on this network is facing such an issue.

#### What I've tried

- After reading various blogs and answers to similar questions I realized it was due to an incorrect DNS address. On correcting it my network started working fine. But after a few hours, the issues returned.
- I tried reinstalling TCP/IP using the following command:
  [`netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt`](https://serverfault.com/a/527291/579763)
- It resolved the issue for a few hours but the issue returned after a while.
- I tried connecting my laptop with a LAN cable to rule out WiFi issues, it was not able to access web pages. Even connecting the laptop to my mobile network through a hotspot doesn't solve this issue.
- Shutting down the laptop and restarting it again produced the same result as above: It works for some time but the issue returns
- I asked my internet service provider for help, but they were not able to resolve this issue.
- This is the screenshot of the command prompt when the network is working fine:

  [image]

  For now, the network is working fine so I don't have a screenshot of the DNS server list when I am facing this issue. But as far as I remember it was showing only `8.8.8.8`.
- A few days ago I rejected the notification to update to windows 11. Could there be any relation of this issue to not updating my OS?

**Changes I made further**

1. I changed the DNS back to the default option (rather than setting it manually)
2. As DNS for IPv16 was not showing in cmd so I disabled it.

I have added the screenshot of cmd in both the conditions now. See if you can make any sense of it.

Below is the photo when the net is working fine
[image: snippet of cmd when net works perfectly fine]

Below is the photo when I was not able to browse anything
[image]
[image]

#### Question

My laptop cannot access web pages in the browser, while applications like Skype work fine. Any attempts so far only help for a few hours. How can I resolve this permanently?

Kindly help me resolve this. It gets very frustrating to stop the work, close all the tabs and restart the laptop every few hours.

Comment: First of all: great work in showing what you've tried so far! Could you perhaps [edit] the question and include what DNS servers you have configured when loading web pages works and when it doesn't? You can see that by running the command `ipconfig /all` and looking for the output marked "DNS Servers".

Comment: Try resetting or setting the DNS address in your router. I use the ISP's DNS address and that has works properly on all devices here for years. Reset the router after changing the DNS address.  Windows 10 works fine. There is NO need to upgrade to Windows 11 to make DNS work.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I have made the edits. Kindly look into it. Thank you.

Comment: @John I use ISP's address only. I tried to manually set it just once when I faced this problem. But it was of no help.

Comment: Another thing that may be worthwhile to try is to update the firmware on your router.

Comment: I'm not sure the router plays a role as the DNS setting shown in the screenshot does not refer to the router at all, it only has "external" DNS servers. Additionally, if the router DNS setting was the culprit, other devices on the network would also have this issue.

Comment: 1. You have no IPV6 DNS server shown. For CloudFlare, add 2606:4700:4700::1111 and 2606:4700:4700::1001 . 2. What does *ipconfig /all/* show for *Lease Obtained* and for *Lease Expires*?  See https://theitbros.com/nslookup-command/ 3. Is there a VPN on that PC, and does it show as connected or disconnected?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik
1. I already made the changes you mentioned. I had added the addresses.
2. The lease expires every day. I have added the screenshot at the end by editing the post itself.
3. I don't use any VPN on my pc.

Comment: I have made some edits. If you guys can make some sense of it please help.